# How to arrange documents into specific types of positions using ActiveQt?

Tags: c++, qt, docx

I'm using Qt to create a merging document app. Sometimes,I have 4 documents ( in 4 different .docx files ). They need to be arranged into these types of positions:

[image: position 1]

[image: position 2]

My solutions for this are:

Solution 1: While adding documents, add a number of tabs and/or spaces to the document .
Solution 2: Add 1x4 or 2x2 pre-defined tables and add the documents to them.

I use `dynamicCall("InsertFile(QString&)"` to add documents, However, I don't know **what functions to use and how to implement them to arrange the 4 documents into those positions.**

Providing:

All documents is about the size of "xxxxxxxxx". It's not longer than half a line. 
Lots of types of documents will be added to just one file. Some of them will have different positioning from these 2 types ( for example: just one long paragraph ). (-> So I don't think you can use columns )

What position to use will be decided by the user when they use the app.

Comment: It is likely more about MS Word then Qt. You need to study the interface of that COM object.